Access to apache2 site
So I have access to the server via SSH. This is how the configurations are set
<VirtualHost *81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    RedirectMatch 404 \.pdf$
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            allow from all                
    </Directory>

    <Files  ~ "\.pdf$">
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
      allow from host 85.214.165.56
    </Files>

</VirtualHost>

But still get 403 Forbidden why try to access the domain. Shouldn't allow from all directive give permissions to everyone ?
